# Changing the background image for the default base-2014 theme in Bolt cms

Tags: html, css, bolt-cms

I am trying to change the background image for the base-2014 theme in Bolt. I have uploaded the picture into the images folder inside the theme folder.I am editing the html code that is in `_header.twig` file in order to change the background. I am applying the background in the body tag. Although plain colours seem to work,when I apply an image it does not display it as the background.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>
      {% if record.title is defined %}{{ record.title|striptags }} | {% endif %}
      {{ app.config.get('general/sitename') }}
      {% if record.title is not defined and app.config.get('general/payoff') %} | {{ app.config.get('general/payoff') }}{% endif %}
    </title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="{{ paths.theme }}css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{{ paths.theme }}css/pwr-bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha256-7s5uDGW3AHqw6xtJmNNtr+OBRJUlgkNJEo78P4b0yRw= sha512-nNo+yCHEyn0smMxSswnf/OnX6/KwJuZTlNZBjauKhTK0c+zT+q5JOCx0UFhXQ6rJR9jg6Es8gPuD2uZcYDLqSw==" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

  </head>
  <body background =" website.net/theme/base-2014/imagesbg.jpg">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
```

Can someone guide me as to where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The background attribute is not supported anymore since HTML5 use css instead add a style tag between the head tag with the following code.

```
<style>
body {
    background-image:url(bgimage.jpg)"
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use this method if you want to put it in the HTML attribute :

```
<body background ="{{paths.theme}}/backgrounds/yourimage.jpg">
```

You call the path like this {{ paths.theme }} and put the picture you want into a folder named "backgrounds" (or as you want) and finally the name of your picture.